how to disable iterm2 highlight frame
I updated iTerm2 to version 3.5.1, and everything is fine, but a rather weird frame appears when I click on the frame in the window.
I want to disable this new feature, but I cannot find options to disable this.


Indeed, from now I won't update iTerm anymore. The time has come for overdevelopment :/

@lortschi I think you mean "The developer has entered the stage of 'overdevelopment' of his product"? In which case, I completely agree.

The feature is called "Selection" which can be turned off via the Settings/General/Selection menu.


Thank you so much, it was driving me insane. It's a useful feature, but all-or-nothing and bound to a single click, when people will often click on a window or pane to make it active? Can't change how the highlighting works, can't change it to ⌘-click or anything else. Terrible UX.

I opened an issue to hopefully make the UI more informative, so people can find it easier.
